# Не работает урл паттерн в Джанго

Tags: django

Задача передать из урл в функцию юзернейм пользователя. Что делаю:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm text-muted" href="{% url 'posts:post_edit' username=userobject.username post_id=postobject.id  %}" role="button">
```

Юзернейм уходит в урл:

```
path('<str:username>/<int:post_id>/edit/', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
```

Но не появляется во вью:

```
@login_required
def post_edit(request, post_id, username):
    """Редактирует пост"""
    if request.user.username != username:
        return redirect('post', username=username, post_id=post_id)

    postobject = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = Post()
            text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            if form.cleaned_data['group']:
                group = form.cleaned_data['group']
                objectgroup = Group.objects.filter(id=group)
                post.group = objectgroup[0]
            username = request.user
            post.id = post_id
            post.text = text
            objectuser = User.objects.filter(username=username)
            post.author = objectuser[0]
            post.pub_date = datetime.now()
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                f'/profile/{username}',
                RequestContext(request)
            )
    else:
        form = PostForm(initial={'text': postobject.text})

    return render(request, 'posts/post_edit.html', {
        'form': form,
        'post_id': post_id,
        'is_edit': True
    })
```

появляется ошибка:[image]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

А разве в паттернах есть str?
не должно быть так?

```
path('<slug:username>/<int:post_id>/edit/', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы во вьюхе сравниваете request.user.username с входящим username, то почему бы сразу не передать request.user.username в url?

```
<a class="btn btn-sm text-muted" href="{% url 'posts:post_edit' username=request.user.username post_id=postobject.id  %}" role="button">
```